# How should I impute a 100% missing element of a composite variable?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, missing-data, data-imputation, multinomial-logit

I want to model the variable $Y$ (score 1 to 10) that is a composite of 5 ordinal variables $Y_{a:e}$ with the same levels (0 = "not at all", 1 = "a little bit", 2="a lot"). $Y_{a:e}$ has been observed on the same individuals (n=500) at 3 points in time; $Y_{a:e;t1}$, $Y_{a:e;t2}$ and $Y_{a:e;t3}$. The aim is to compute the adjusted (i.e.: model-based) prevalence of $Y>5$ at each of these time points. So, ultimately, my overall score variable $Y$ is transformed into a binary variable.

Unfortunately, 1 of the 5 ordinal variables is 100% missing at one of these time point (e.g.: $Y_{a;t3}$ is completely unobserved) , so the score (0-10) and furthermore the prevalence $Y>5$ can't be computed. How can I estimate the score at this time point, given that the composite variable $Y$ was partly unobserved?

I thought of 3 solutions:

a) Replace missing $Y_{a;t3}$ with $Y_{b;t3}$ because $Y_{b}$ is similar to $Y_{a}$, however gives a little bit more specific information (e.g.: $Y_{b}$ = "Do you feel anxious at work?" vs $Y_{a}$ = "Do you feel anxious in general?")

b) Average $Y_{b:e;t3}$ and attribute to result to $Y_{a;t3}$. So basically, $Y_{a;t3}$ = ($Y_{b;t3} +Y_{c;t3}+Y_{d;t3}+Y_{e;t3})/4$

c) Treat the problem as a "machine learning" problem. Predict missing $Y_{a;t3}$ through a multinominal proportional odds regression trained on $Y_{a;t2}$ with numerous predictors that are relevant to predict the outcome.

I have a slight preference for solution c), but I would enjoy any advice that that get me closer to attribute unbiased values to $Y_{a;t3}$. If solution c) seems reasonable, what can I do to maximize my model prediction performance?

Comment: Do you know why it is missing? It seems highly unusual one particular measurement to miss from all subjects at a specific time-point. Yes, imputation can be relevant (i.e. do your option c.) but I would treat imputation in this case as something *very* sketchy because it would make some *very strong* assumptions. At best it would have to assume that $Y_{a;t3}$ is evolving like $Y_{b:3;t3}$ across time (if they do). I would actually suggest doing two analysis one with imputation and one were the prevalence $Y$ is redefined *without* $Y_{a}$.

Comment: thanks @user11852, the sensitivity analysis that you are suggesting sounds right. The variable is missing because of an informatic glitch, and can't be recovered...